# How to generate a token for PowerBI?

Tags: json, azure-active-directory, httpresponse, azure-logic-apps, powerbi-embedded

i'm actually lost in the See of information. i have found a lot of Resources [like this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/datasets-generate-token-in-group#required-scope) but NONE works for some reason. so i have already created an AD app for PowerBI using the Power BI embedding setup tool. I choose the ***Embed Power BI for your organization's internal users—for enterprises.***

[image]

i didn't know what i should have given as home page URL so i typed a local host which i think is what that's messing everything up.

[image]

[image]

then i gave all the permissions it needs at the end i got this:

[image: after completion of making AD ap]

so my problem is that i want to Refresh a ***specific Dataset*** with HTTP request tool in a Logic app. the link looks like this:

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{G_id}/datasets/{D_id}/refresh
```

but i found out before that i need a token for it because it returns 403 Forbidden Error. so i read Docs and got lost. i tried [This Page](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/How-to-generate-the-authorization-code-and-the-access-token-to/m-p/409409#M12204) which suggests this request:

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
data: {
    grant_type: password
    scope: openid
    resource: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
    client_id: {Client ID} (got this from Azure Active Directory app)
    username: {PBI Account Username} (I used email and User from the Picture above but did's work)
    password: {PBI Account Username} (I used email and User from the Picture above but did's work)
}
```

when i tried it, it return this error:

```
{
"error": "invalid_request",
"error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: 247iop60-42-407f-a184-1e15e500\r\nCorrelation ID: f3ca10-d034b7-13-50747a3e\r\nTimestamp: 2022-08-17 11:40:05Z",
"error_codes": [
    900144
],
"timestamp": "2022-08-17 11:40:05Z",
"trace_id": "2473f960-3a42-407f-a184-1e15eb24d500",
"correlation_id": "f35cca10-d034-4eb7-9113-507642647a3e",
"error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=900144"
```

}

maybe i'm doing sth in Postman App wrong:
[image]

Comment: Are you the owner of the dataset? Only the owner can refresh it.

Comment: yes......... @AndreyNikolov

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

```hs
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
data: {
    grant_type: password
    scope: openid
    resource: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
    client_id: {Client ID} 
    username: {Username} 
    password: {Username}
    }
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to give the parameters in **`x-www-form-urlencoded`** like below:

Make sure to give **App secret** in **`client_secret`** parameter.

[image]

**I got the tokens for PowerBI successfully like below:**

[image]

***After generating the tokens try refreshing the dataset with HTTP request tool in a Logic app.***

Comment: tnx for your answer but right now i'm getting this error, i'm sure that my credentials are correct.

{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.\r\nTrace ID: --47a4-8022-\r\nCorrelation ID: -c8ac--baea-\r\nTimestamp: 2022-08-:01:55Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50126
    ],
    "timestamp": "-08-08:01:55Z",
    "trace_id": "-6e78--8022-",
    "correlation_id": "-c8ac-4b3a--",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50126"
}

Comment: i edited the beginning of my Question. is "Embed Power BI for your organization's internal users—for enterprises" the right choice?

Comment: Yes, you have to select "Embed Power BI for your organization's internal users—for enterprises"

Comment: Make sure whether you signed in with admin account or not and make sure both credentials PowerBI and Postman are same.

Comment: can problem be Federated authentication? because my company uses that and yes i am the admin of the PowerBI Dataset

Comment: The problem might be with Federated authentication. In my environment I was able to get the access token for PoweBI using Azure AD Authentication.