# steps to create PowerBI API token

Tags: oauth-2.0, httprequest, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-api, azure-oauth

i'm using this URL `https://login.windows.net/(the Tenant ID of the App that i made in Azure AD)/oauth2/token` to create a Token for PowerBI API. my postman looks like this:

[image]

but when i use this Access token to do some operations like getting a list of reports in a Dataset i get **401 Unauthorized**:

[image]

exactly which steps i have taken so far can be seen in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73388168/how-to-generate-a-token-for-powerbi). I also haven't created a Service Principal, is that needed here? Am i missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow all the steps, it's working fine for me.

Please check the API permissions provided for your registered app.
You can check the required permission API Permissions -> Add a permission -> Power BI Service and select the required permission.

For Instance, We need these permissions to access the datasets:

[image: permissions required to access the datasets]

You can also try the same with the 'try it' feature from here:

[Datasets - Get Dataset In Group - REST API (Power BI Power BI REST APIs) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-dataset-in-group#code-try-0)

Comment: Tnx for the answer. when i click at Try it, i have to sign into my Organisation Account. i'm guessing that might be an issue because we use Federated Oauth.